# Overriding Content Gallery Layout to Contact Gallery Layout

Tags: joomla-3.x, template-override, layout

we have on our template the possibility to creat an Gallery View for Content / Categories.
it looks like the following:
[image]

so and now - i'm trying to get the same view for the contacts.
In contacts there are also categories and items, so i guess it should be possible.

i copied the following files in to the template folder for contact (com_contact):

```
gallery.xml
gallery_children.php
gallery_item.php
gallery_links.php
```

i'm getting now an error in the main file gallery.php:
Notice: Undefined property: ContactViewCategory::$intro_items in /srv/www/vhosts/kubler.ch/httpdocs/templates/as002057/html/com_contact/category/gallery.php on line 103

on these lines around it looks like this (101-104:

```
<?php
$introcount = (count($this->intro_items));
$counter = 0;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy files from one component view to another. View have been coded specially for that specific component. The variable names for `com_content` are different to `com_contact`

Don't try and do things to quick way ;) What I would suggest doing is creating your basic Template Override by copying the view files from `com_contact` to your template.

From here on, start merging the structural changes from your gallery into the `com_contact` override. It may seem a little time consuming but it's the only way.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did already did what you said.
I copied the gallery files from the template overrides folder com_content and copied it to the override folder of the template com_contact.
So actually i'm able now to choose the Gallery View as new Menu Type.
But i need some help with PHP - the categories of the contacts are not showing up.

Comment: No, I said **not** to copy the gallery files from `com_content` to `com_contact` as these views are specifically for articles, not contacts.

Comment: yes but how can i get the gallery view to work on contacts then?

Comment: I've have explained this in my answer. Please read it again